# Tips to correct photograph which was taken by an iPhone 11 with light sensor issues

Tags: photo-editing, software, color-correction

I took a photograph with an iPhone 11 which has a light sensor issue. Due to that, the photograph is purple-ish and has a strange line in the top. Part of the photograph (the sky) depicting the phenomenon is shown below (I will not post here the whole photograph for privacy reasons):

[image]

By using phone's photograph editor I can in some way correct the color, but I cannot remove the line (see picture below). Do you know any simple tool that could easily remove such line (there is, for instance, Photoshop, but I would rather prefer to use an open-source software or one imbedded into a web browser)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/), you would just use the [Clone tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-clone.html) to replicate an adjacent part of the image on the line.

[image]

There are more powerful tools (content aware fill) but they require plugins and may be overkill.

[image]